# Mountain Lion - Change configuration file (php.ini) path

Tags: php, symfony-1.4

I'm trying to get **Symfony 1.4** running on my Mac. When I type "`./symfony doctrine:build --all`" to create the database, I receive the error "`Couldn't located driver named mysql`". I've searched for this error and I'm told I need to uncomment this extension in php.ini. I have done this but I'm still getting the same error!

When I type "php --ini" in terminal, I get:

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /usr/local/lib
Loaded Configuration File:         /usr/local/lib/php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: (none)
Additional .ini files parsed:      (none)
```

I want to change this path so that is uses the php.ini in XAMPP.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: Why use XAMPP? Mac OS comes with Apache and PHP, and you can easily download and instal mysql. Here's a [tutorial](http://coolestguyplanettech.com/downtown/install-and-configure-apache-mysql-php-and-phpmyadmin-osx-108-mountain-lion)

Comment: Have you tried MAMP? I reckon it's the easiest to setup.

Answer (score 0):

Use the PHP-binary inside your XAMP-Bundle. I would expect it to be located somewhere like `/Applications/XAMPP.app/Contents/Ressources/php/bin/php`. But I can not verify this path currently. So you might have to search inside the `/Applications/XAMPP.app` folder for it. Perhaps `find /Applications/XAMPP.app -name php` might help.

So you might want to add that path to your path file before calling the symfony-executable by setting `PATH=/Applications/XAMPP.app/Contents/Ressources/php/bin:$PATH`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your responses, but I managed to do what I set out to in the end...

If you run "sudo pico /private/etc/paths" in Terminal, you can then add the path to php in XAMPP to the top of this file, which in my case was "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin".

If you then restart Terminal and run "which php", you will see the new path.

Thanks